# Is there any reason not to upload to arxiv?

Tags: arxiv

Is there any downside to putting your work on arxiv before submitting it to a conference? As a student my advisor always did the conference submission first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1/ Someone could improve upon your work and becomes the state-of-the-art solution.   This means the glory goes to the latest work.

This is area specific, where in some areas the goal is to break a certain barrier or performance of the state-of-the-art solutions for a given problem.

2/ Some conferences or/and journals do not allow preprints to be available on the Internet.